# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then is the pseudo-inverse $f^+$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assume that $\sigma$-algebra contains Borel sets and let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define $g=f^+:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(x) = 0$ if $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = 1/f(x)$ if $f(x)\neq0$. I am trying to prove that $g$ is measurable but not confident in my trial. Would you check the proof below?

Since $f$ is continuous and $f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow g(x) = 0$, $f^{-1}(0) = g^{-1}(0)$ is closed, so measurable. Let $A = \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid f(x) = 0\}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\setminus A$. The restriction of $g$ into $B$, $g|_B$, is continuous in $B$. Let $V\in \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary open set. Then, $W = V\setminus\{0\}$ is open and $g^{-1}(W) = g|_B^{-1}(W) \subset B$ is open, so measurable. Since $g^{-1}(0)$ and $g^{-1}(W)$ are measurable, $g^{-1}(V)$ is measurable. Therefore, $g$ is measurable.

Comment: That proof works.

Comment: @Mathemagical Thanks for your answer.